# Set default route to controller in an area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We are trying to set the default route for our webapp to an action on a controller in an area. Our project setup looks like so:

[image]

The AccountController looks like this:

```
[Area("Dashboard")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And in our startup.cs we map the area route and the default route like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

We want to use an action in the AccountController as our default route but when we do this we get an error saying that the localhost page can't be found. The URL it is trying to access is: `http://localhost:56893/`.

If we change the startup.cs file to look like this instead:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
          name: "areas",
          template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

and then have a HomeController in the Area that does a simple redirect:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account", new { area = "Dashboard" });
    }
}
```

this seems to work fine.

Comment: May be you should specify area also in default route

Comment: @Bharadwaj we had tried that but never got it working. Do you have an example of how we can define the area?

Comment: In template try by adding `{area=Dashboard}` before `{controller=Home}`

Comment: @Bharadwaj Unfortuantely we have tried that previously and it didn't work.

Comment: There will be one registration file specific to the area. Are you configuring this in there?

Comment: @Bharadwaj I don't think so - I'm not sure what registration file you are referring to.

Comment: How did you added that Dashboard area? Have you created the file structure by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

change the routing to this and do not forget to use control + 5   in your browser

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{area=Dashboard}/{controller=Account}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```